# The maximum modulus of the difference between points of a complex segment of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $D$ be ad open set of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function.

Let $z_0 \in D$ and let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R_+}$ such that the segment $S$ from $z_0$ to $z_0+x_0$ is in $D$

I would like to know if it is true that;
$$
\max_{z,s \in S}|f(z)-f(s)|=|f(z_0)-f(z_0+x_0)|
$$

Comment: Definitely not true since you can have $f(z_0)=f(z_0+x_0)$ without $f$ being constant - see $z^2$ in the plane with the segment being $[-1,1]$

Comment: thanks so much @Conrad for your answer

Comment: you are welcome